# white edge around objects with alpha - cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, transparency

I had a problem with white edges around my materials, especialy with trees like this. And yes I tried every solution what I found there and on google.(alpha-straight,progressive..etc) The texture is in .tiff with alpha channel.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

After a while I found that problem is the .tiff format. 
The solution is very simply **resave the .tiff to .png** with transparency.
[image]